# Socket object in C++

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm trying to write a basic socket program that layers reliable data transport over UDP in C++. I've been reading beej.us and googling, but I'm still really confused about the socket object. I come from a Python/Java background and have never programmed in C++, but from what I understand, the program that our professor has given us to complete should be using some sort of socket object, correct?

So how come from what I can see [here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/sys/socket.h.html), there does not seem to be a getter nor a setter for the socket object? What is `bind()` using as a reference when it is called to modify a socket object?
I see that there is an int called sockfd that seems to be identifying each unique socket, but I don't see how simply calling that number will grab a reference to the socket object with that particular sockfd.

Also, it seems like `beej.us` and a bunch of youtube tutorials all use `getaddrinfo()` to create the socket object, but that function does not exist in the code provided by the professor, and the instructions indicate that we do not need to write any additional functions..

The format we have to use is pasted below. There are two files, one for the server and one for the client. Then is a header with all the functions inside.

rdt.h:

```
#ifndef RDT1_H
#define RDT1_H

#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <netdb.h>


#define PAYLOAD 1000    //size of data payload of the RDT layer

//----- Type defines --------------------------------------------
typedef unsigned char       u8b_t;      // a char
typedef unsigned short      u16b_t;     // 16-bit word
typedef unsigned int        u32b_t;     // 32-bit word 

int rdt_socket();
int rdt_bind(int fd, u16b_t port);
int rdt_target(int fd, char * peer_name, u16b_t peer_port);
int rdt_send(int fd, char * msg, int length);
int rdt_recv(int fd, char * msg, int length);
int rdt_close(int fd);

/* Application process calls this function to create the RDT socket. 
   return   -> the socket descriptor on success, -1 on error
*/
int rdt_socket() {
}

/* Application process calls this function to specify the IP address
   and port number used by itself and assigns them to the RDT socket.
   return   -> 0 on success, -1 on error
*/
int rdt_bind(int fd, u16b_t port){
}

/* Application process calls this function to specify the IP address
   and port number used by remote process and associates them to the 
   RDT socket.
   return   -> 0 on success, -1 on error
*/
int rdt_target(int fd, char * peer_name, u16b_t peer_port){

}

/* Application process calls this function to transmit a message to
   target (rdt_target) remote process through RDT socket.
   msg      -> pointer to the application's send buffer
   length   -> length of application message
   return   -> size of data sent on success, -1 on error
*/
int rdt_send(int fd, char * msg, int length){

}

/* Application process calls this function to wait for a message 
   from the remote process; the caller will be blocked waiting for
   the arrival of the message.
   msg      -> pointer to the receiving buffer
   length   -> length of receiving buffer
   return   -> size of data received on success, -1 on error
*/
int rdt_recv(int fd, char * msg, int length){

}

/* Application process calls this function to close the RDT socket.
*/
int rdt_close(int fd){

}

#endif
```

server.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CPORT 59079
#define SPORT 59080

#define STORAGE "Store"

static float LOSS_RATE=0.0, ERR_RATE=0.0;

/* uncomment this part for part 1 */
#include "rdt-part1.h"
#define MSG_LEN PAYLOAD


/* uncomment this part for part 2 
#include "rdt-part2.h"
#define MSG_LEN PAYLOAD
*/

/* uncomment this part for part 3 
#include "rdt-part3.h"
#define MSG_LEN PAYLOAD*W
*/


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sockfd;
    char filepath[200]; 
    char * s;
    char msg[MSG_LEN];
    struct stat sbuf;   
    FILE * testfile;
    int file_len, len;
    int received=0;

    if (argc != 2) {
        printf("Usage: %s 'client hostname'\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }

    /* update random seed */
    srand(time(NULL));
    /* remove the above line if you want to get the same random 
       sequence for each run - good for testing */

    /* check whether the folder exists */
    if (stat(STORAGE, &sbuf) != 0) {
        printf("Directory ./%s does not exist!!\n", STORAGE);
        printf("Please create the directory %s before start up the server.\n", STORAGE);
        exit(0);
    }

    /* read in packet loss rate and error rate */
    s = getenv("PACKET_LOSS_RATE");
    if (s != NULL) LOSS_RATE = strtof(s, NULL);
    s = getenv("PACKET_ERR_RATE");
    if (s != NULL) ERR_RATE = strtof(s, NULL);
    printf("PACKET_LOSS_RATE = %.2f, PACKET_ERR_RATE = %.2f\n", LOSS_RATE, ERR_RATE);

    // create RDT socket
    sockfd = rdt_socket();

    //specify my own IP address & port number, because if I do not specify, others can not send things to me.
    rdt_bind(sockfd, SPORT);    

    //specify the IP address & port number of my partner 
    rdt_target(sockfd, argv[1], CPORT);

    /* a very simple handshaking protocol */
    // wait for client request
    memset(msg, '\0', MSG_LEN);
    len = rdt_recv(sockfd, msg, MSG_LEN);
    file_len = atoi(msg);
    printf("Received client request: file size = %d\n", file_len);

    memset(msg, '\0', MSG_LEN);
    len = rdt_recv(sockfd, msg, MSG_LEN);
    sprintf(filepath, "%s/%s", STORAGE, msg);
    testfile = fopen(filepath, "w");
    if (!testfile) {
        printf("Cannot open the target file: ./%s for write\n", filepath);

        // send the ERROR response
        memset(msg, '\0', MSG_LEN);
        sprintf(msg, "ERROR");
        rdt_send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
        goto END;
    } else {
        printf("Open file %s for writing successfully\n", filepath);
        // send the ERROR response
        memset(msg, '\0', MSG_LEN);
        sprintf(msg, "OKAY");
        rdt_send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));
    }

    /* start the file transfer */   
    printf("Start receiving the file . . .\n");
    // receive the file contents
    while (received < file_len) {
        memset(msg, 0, MSG_LEN);
        len = rdt_recv(sockfd, msg, MSG_LEN);
        fwrite(msg, sizeof(char), len, testfile);
        received += len;
        printf("Received a message of size %d bytes\n", len);
    }

    printf("Complete the file transfer.\n");

END:    
    // close the file
    fclose(testfile);

    // close the rdt socket
    rdt_close(sockfd);

    printf("Server program terminated\n");

    return 0;
}
```

client.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

#define CPORT 59079
#define SPORT 59080

static float LOSS_RATE=0.0, ERR_RATE=0.0;

/* uncomment this part for part 1 */
#include "rdt-part1.h"
#define MSG_LEN PAYLOAD


/* uncomment this part for part 2 
#include "rdt-part2.h"
#define MSG_LEN PAYLOAD
*/

/* uncomment this part for part 3 
#include "rdt-part3.h"
#define MSG_LEN PAYLOAD*W
*/


int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int sockfd;
    FILE * testfile;
    int filelength, len;
    char * fname, * s;
    char msg[MSG_LEN];
    int sent = 0;
    struct timeval starttime, endtime;
    double lapsed;

    if (argc != 3) {
        printf("Usage: %s 'server hostname' 'filename'\n", argv[0]);
        exit(0);
    }   

    /* update random seed */
    srand(time(NULL));
    /* remove the above line if you want to get the same random 
       sequence for each run - good for testing */

    /* read in packet loss rate and error rate */
    s = getenv("PACKET_LOSS_RATE");
    if (s != NULL) LOSS_RATE = strtof(s, NULL);
    s = getenv("PACKET_ERR_RATE");
    if (s != NULL) ERR_RATE = strtof(s, NULL);
    printf("PACKET_LOSS_RATE = %.2f, PACKET_ERR_RATE = %.2f\n", LOSS_RATE, ERR_RATE);

    fname=argv[2];
    //open file
    if (!(testfile = fopen(fname, "r"))) {
        printf("Open file failed.\nProgram terminated.");
        exit(0);
    }
    printf("Open file successfully \n");
    //get the file size
    fseek(testfile, 0L, SEEK_END); 
    filelength = ftell(testfile);   
    printf("File bytes are %d \n",filelength);
    fseek(testfile, 0L, SEEK_SET);

    // create RDT socket
    sockfd = rdt_socket();

    //specify my own IP address & port number, because if I do not specify, others can not send things to me.
    rdt_bind(sockfd, CPORT);     

    //specify the IP address & port number of my partner 
    rdt_target(sockfd, argv[1], SPORT);

    /* a very simple handshaking protocol */ 
    //send the size of the file
    memset(msg, '\0', MSG_LEN);
    sprintf(msg, "%d", filelength);
    rdt_send(sockfd, msg, strlen(msg));  

    //send the file name to server
    rdt_send(sockfd, fname, strlen(fname));

    //wait for server response
    memset(msg, '\0', MSG_LEN);
    len = rdt_recv(sockfd, msg, MSG_LEN);
    if (strcmp(msg, "ERROR") == 0) {
        printf("Server experienced fatal error.\nProgram terminated.\n");
        goto END;
    } else
        printf("Receive server response\n");

    /* start the data transfer */
    printf("Start the file transfer . . .\n");
    gettimeofday(&starttime, NULL);
    // send the file contents
    while (sent < filelength) {
        if ((filelength-sent) < MSG_LEN)
            len = fread(msg, sizeof(char), filelength-sent, testfile);
        else
            len = fread(msg, sizeof(char), MSG_LEN, testfile);
        rdt_send(sockfd, msg, len);
        sent += len;
        usleep(1000);
    }
    gettimeofday(&endtime, NULL);
    printf("Complete the file transfer.\n");
    lapsed = (endtime.tv_sec - starttime.tv_sec)*1.0 + (endtime.tv_usec - starttime.tv_usec)/1000000.0;
    printf("Total elapse time: %.3f s\tThroughtput: %.2f KB/s\n", lapsed, filelength/lapsed/1000.0);

END:    
    // close the file
    fclose(testfile);

    // close the rdt socket
    rdt_close(sockfd);
    printf("Client program terminated\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What?  You can't call anything on a sockfd type, nor do you try to.  It's an opaque token supplied by the OS.

Comment: @MartinJames sockfd is a type?? isn't it just an int? I'm sorry I'm so confused.

Comment: @gnawgnaw: sockfd is a handler.  This means that you shouldn't care what it exactly is.  You get it when you create a socket and you use it as a parameter when you refer to the socket.

Comment: The socket api is a c api. No objects, no getters, no setters. The sockfd int is a handle to the socket. You could think of it as the index into an array of socket objects if that makes it conceptually clearer. Use the man pages to find out what each function does, they are available online.